# merge image by gd in php

Tags: php, merge, gd

I want to merge two images by gd library in php
first image is my local image which is in the same folder of my file
but i want to get the second image from somewhere else in internet
i mean , the second image is something like this : http://www.somewhere.com/pics/image.jpg
i try to merge but it doesnt work :(
this is my code:
source is my jpeg URL. it works when jpeg file is in the same folder !!

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

if ( isset( $_POST['source'] ) ){

$source = $_POST['source'];

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng( 'logo.png' );
$watermark_width = imagesx( $watermark );
$watermark_height = imagesy( $watermark );

$image = imagecreatetruecolor( $watermark_width, $watermark_height );
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $source );

$imagesize = getimagesize( $source );
$x = $imagesize[0] - $watermark_width - 10;
$y = $imagesize[1] - $watermark_height - 10;

imagecopymerge( $image, $watermark, $x, $y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 20 );
imagejpeg( $image );
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is submitted for the "source" parameter? If it's a URL, your code should work as expected provided the "fopen wrappers" have been enabled. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php. Also, you're overriding `$image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to solve this. You can use `curl` to pull the remote image down to your local machine. Since you said your code works when the image is in the same folder, you should be all set then.